# Find by biggest difference between elements on embedded object array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given a list of products like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a594f8eff9da13c9d415a63"),
    "productId" : "xxx",
    "date" : "2018-09-13",
    "prices" : [
        {
            "country" : "en",
            "price" : 16.5,
            "currency" : "EUR"
        },
        {
            "country" : "es",
            "price" : 17.78,
            "currency" : "EUR"
        },
        {
            "country" : "fr",
            "price" : 18.08,
            "currency" : "EUR"
        },
        {
            "country" : "de",
            "price" : 18.89,
            "currency" : "EUR"
        },
        {
            "country" : "it",
            "price" : 27.49,
            "currency" : "EUR"
        }
    ]
}
```

Given a country code and a date, is there any way to find the products for that date and order by biggest different between price for the country?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In that case you cannot access the country price, I think its better to make it in this structure `en: {"price" : 16.5,
            "currency" : "EUR"}`

Comment: Can you add the expected response to the post ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

1. you want the biggest difference between the given country and **any other country** and
2. there are **no duplicate product ids** (if there are, the latest product will be used, thanks to this line `"$last": "$prices"`),

try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "date": "2018-09-13" // replace with date variable
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productId",
      "prices": {
        "$last": "$prices"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "pricesObj": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$prices",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$this.country",
            "v": "$$this.price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "pricesObj": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$pricesObj"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "reference": "$pricesObj.es" // replace with country variable
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "differences": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$prices",
          "in": {
            "country": "$$this.country",
            "difference": {
              "$abs": {
                "$subtract": [
                  "$$this.price",
                  "$reference"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "biggestDifference": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$differences",
          "initialValue": {
            difference: 0
          },
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$gt": [
                  "$$this.difference",
                  "$$value.difference"
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "biggestDifference": "$biggestDifference.difference"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "biggestDifference": -1
    }
  }
])
```

I'm sure it could be expressed more concisely, but it works: https://mongoplayground.net/p/y67jhhFBB9l

The output looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "xxy",
    "biggestDifference": 12295.109999999999
  },
  {
    "_id": "xxx",
    "biggestDifference": 98.72
  }
]
```

for this input:

```
[
  {
    "productId": "xxx",
    "date": "2018-09-13",
    "prices": [
      {
        "country": "en",
        "price": 116.5,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "es",
        "price": 17.78,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "fr",
        "price": 18.08,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "de",
        "price": 18.89,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "it",
        "price": 27.49,
        "currency": "EUR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productId": "xxy",
    "date": "2018-09-13",
    "prices": [
      {
        "country": "en",
        "price": 16.5,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "es",
        "price": 17.78,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "fr",
        "price": 18.08,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "de",
        "price": 12312.89,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
        "country": "it",
        "price": 997.49,
        "currency": "EUR"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jaksz,

Finally, I'm using this approach that works like a charm (because the smaller price is always in the first position of the array):

```
db.productPrices.aggregate(
                     [
  {
    "$match": {
    "date": "2018-09-13" // replace with date variable
    }
  },
  {
      "$group": {
      "_id": "$productId",
      "prices": {
          "$last": "$prices"
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields": {
      "pricesObj": {
          "$map": {
              "input": "$prices",
          "in": {
                  "k": "$$this.country",
            "v": "$$this.price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields": {
      "pricesObj": {
          "$arrayToObject": "$pricesObj"
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields": {
      "reference": "$pricesObj.es" // replace with country variable
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields": {
      "cheapest": {
          "$arrayElemAt": ["$prices", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields": {
      "difference": {
          "$abs": {
              "$subtract": ["$reference", "$cheapest.price"]

        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "prices": "$prices",
      "difference": "$difference"
    }
  },
  {
      "$sort": {
      "difference": -1
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```